# Apache Core Dump file deletes itself on physical machine restart

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, dump

I am having an issue which there must be a simple solution I am not seeing, but I have googled and googled to no avail.

The issue I am having is when I do a server *(physical machine)* restart, every time Apache tells me that `/tmp/apache2-gbd-dump` doesn't exist and to check the `httpd.conf` file. Well I check the conf file, and sure enough it's calling to a `/tmp/apache2-gbd-dump` for Core Dump. The issue is **this file does not in fact exist**. When I look at the logs, that is the only warning/error that is associated with the start failure.

So I've tried to *create* the file, `chown` it to `www-data:www-data` and `chmod` it to `777`. And this *works*, in that I can now `sudo service apache2 start`. As soon as I restart the physical machine, the Core Dump file disappears, and I have to recreate the file again **manually** to get Apache to start, since it fials it's automatic start up. This obviously will not work when this turns into a production server. Has anyone any insight as to what I can look into to find out *why* this is happening? Here is the code inside the conf file if anyone sees a pertinent issue, can you please point it out?

```
CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump

LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include httpd.conf
Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your /tmp is a `tmpfs` mount. You need to change the core path to be in /var or somewhere else.

See `core_pattern` in the `man core` page.

Comment: Good point ...  I will check that and post back ...

Comment: Even if it's not /tmp may be cleaned automatically on boot.

Comment: Turns out it is a mount point for this install, and thus was being cleaned out and files recreated on start-up.  Thank you for your help!